# Difference between train.RMSPropOptimizer and tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer (tensorflow)

Tags: tensorflow

I am implementing an autoencoder. The cost function I am trying to minimize is mean square error. When I use RMSPropOptimizer, the output is good. But with GradientDescentOptimizer, the output is not good. So can anyone please explain the differences in between these two optimizer ?

Answer (score 1):

GradientDescentOptimizer implements the most basic version of [Gradient Descent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gradient_descent) while RMSPropOptimizer implements an adaptive version of [Stochastic Gradient Descent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_gradient_descent) called [RMS Prop "Root Mean Squared Propagation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_gradient_descent#RMSProp).

Basic gradient descent is the slowest of any of the neural network optimizers, you will want to run it for a much longer number of epochs if you want to achieve results similar to RMSProp. In fact just about anyone of the other methods:

tf.train.AdagradOptimizer, 
tf.train.AdagradDAOptimizer, 
tf.train.MomentumOptimizer, 
tf.train.AdamOptimizer, 
tf.train.FtrlOptimizer,...

will give you better results than gradient descent.